# SQL: Move duplicates to another table where condition

Tags: sql, duplicates, insert-into

I am quite new to SQL and Stackoverflow, so pardon the layout of my post.
Currently, I am struggling with putting the following workflow into an executable  SQL statement:

I have a table containing the following columns:

1. ID (not unique)
2. PARTYTYPE (1 or 2)
3. DATE column
4. several other, not relevant columns

Now I need to find those observations (rows) that have the same ID and same PARTYTYPE but are not the most recent, i.e. have a date in the DATE column that is less than the most recent for the given combination of PARTYTYPE and ID. The rows that satisfy this condition need to be moved to another table with the same table scheme in order to archive them.

Is there an efficient, yet simple way to accomplish this in SQL?
I have been looking for a long time, but since it involves finding duplicates with certain conditions and inserting it into a table, it is a rather specific problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO table_history
select ID, PARTYTYPE, count(*) as count_
from table
group by ID, PARTYTYPE, DATE
having DATE = MAX(DATE)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe the SQL almost exactly conforms to a correlated subquery:

```
INSERT INTO table_history( . . . )
    select t.*
    from table t
    where date < (select max(date)
                  from table t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.partytype = t.partytype
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. But the issue is that I my table_history (I guess in your post that is t2) does not yet contain data and also should not affect the decision whether a row is a duplicate. But leaning on your answer, I think I found something that might work: 

INSERT INTO table
select *
fromtable as p1
where GOODTHROUGHDATE < (Select max(GOODTHROUGHDATE) from table where DOCUMENTID=p1.DOCUMENTID and where DOCUMENTID=p1.DOCUMENTID)